# Are header files not compiled (C++ Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Just to see if it would work (I know it's awful form), I fully defined a function in a header file and made a corresponding forward declaration for said function in the main cpp file. C++ functions don't need to be defined in the translation unit they're used in, hence why header files are almost entirely just forward declarations (with the exception of inline functions). However, when I tried to compile this project, it said that there were unresolved externals.

When I moved the entire contents of the header file into a source file (removing the header file as well), it compiled just fine and executed as expected. So, are header files just not compiled when building a project, or is there just some exception I don't know about?

Additionally, even when I just go to the header file's properties in the property explorer and set its `File Type` to `C/C++ Code` and change its extension to .cpp, it still won't compile (even though it will if i just delete it and create a fresh source file, which I think is the oddest part).

(I'm working with extensions disabled `/Za`, if that changes anything)

Here's the code file

```
//main.cpp
void foo();

void main()
{
    foo();
}
```

and the header file

```
//test.h
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << 'a';
}
```

Comment: Header files aren't compiled unless pulled into a translation unit via `#include` preprocessing. Since your only .cpp file has no such inclusion, it is not compiled, and therefore nothing within is available to that (and apparently your only) translation unit.

Comment: http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Header files are included by the preprocessor into the compilation unit - `cpp` file. Only the source code in the `cpp` file is compiled by compiler after that.

When you put your function definition into the header `.h` file. You don't include this header file into `main.cpp` and compiler doesn't compile it as preprocessor doesn't include it in `main.cpp`.

You can review the result of preprocessor job by yourself. In Visual Studio use the `/P` option on the [Preprocessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx) property page. For `main.cpp` output will be in `main.i`.

Answer (score 3):

Header files are not compiled on their own, just imagine that the text is actually inside the .cpp file where it is included. This new 'merged' file is what is compiled. So you can put functions in a header file and it will be compiled when it is included in a .cpp file.

The reason it's bad is that if you include it in a second .cpp file it will try to compile again and you will have problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with function definitions in headers is not that they're skipped. The real risk is that they're compiled *twice*, and that's once too many. C++ has something called a One Definition Rule, and you violate that rule by compiling a single function twice.

There's one important exception to mention: `inline` functions are exempt, and may be defined in each translation unit.